# How to redirect a logout button to a certain page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a logout button and when i clicked i want it to go to the home screen that has only the login form. Imagine it is like a pc that when you choose to log out it closes the session, saves the work and then go to the login screen.

The logout button

```
 <div id="Logout">
    <a href="logout.php" id="LogoutAction"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/crystalproject/crystal_project_256x256/apps/exit.png"></a>
    </div>
```

The login form without css:

```
<div id="Login">       
        <form>
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
        <div id="lower">
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </div><!--/ lower-->
        </form>
    </div>
```

I want to go to the login screen when the button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Your `href` in the `<a>` tag will only work if `logout.php` is in the same dir

Try the following:

```
<!-- if logout.php is in the root dir-->    
<a href="/logout.php" id="LogoutAction">

<!-- if logout.php is in another dir -->    
<a href="/anotherDir/logout.php" id="LogoutAction">

<!-- if logout.php is in the upper dir -->    
<a href="../logout.php" id="LogoutAction">

<!-- if logout.php is in a child dir -->    
<a href="./childDir/logout.php" id="LogoutAction">
```

Comment: It is in the same directory

Comment: Then please specify the problem. Do you get an error message?

Comment: No i don't it just opens the new page with the things i wrote on the logout.php

Comment: Ok. You need two php files, let's say `first.php` and `second.php`. Place your `<div id="Login">` in `first.php` and the `<a href="/logout.php" id="LogoutAction">` in `second.php`. Finally in your browser go to `second.php` click on the link and you will be redirected to `first.php`

Answer (score -1):

You have to destroy the session then make a redirection :

```php
header('Location: login.php');
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Into your logout.php

You do whatever you want to logout the user, then redirect to login.php using the header function.

Comment: Alright then how do i customize the logout php to go to `PF1.1.html`?

Comment: It might seem a dumb question but I only learned html, css and javascript in the classes so it's a bit hard to understand

Comment: I don't understand your question.
I replied to your question. The header function makes a redirection so if you want to redirect to PF1.1.html, you do so.

Comment: Ok so you need to learn the basics of php. It's not hard, you can do it.

Comment: I mean in the code i got where do i write the code u gave me then?

Comment: Nowhere. The logout.php is another file. You really need to learn some basics

Comment: I created the logout.php file and wrote `header('Location: PF1.html');` and it didn't go the way i wanted it to

Comment: It went to a page with header('Location; PF1.html') writen on